# SMTPSendFailedException: 501 Syntax error, parameters in command "MAIL FROM:<Auto Notification TE/AND/DEF>" unrecognized or missing

Tags: java, email, smtp, jakarta-mail, lotus-domino

I am trying to send email using java mail api. The email server is Lotus Domino. The server is configured by other people. I have been provided the details. The mail from address format is like `"Auto Notification TE/AND/DEF"`.But it is giving the exception -

> org.springframework.mail.MailSendException: Failed messages:
>   com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSendFailedException: 501 Syntax error,
>   parameters in command "MAIL FROM:"
>   unrecognized or missing

Is the format wrong? Or the from address in not present?
Any help would be great for me.

Comment: Please paste the sample code with exception message.Possibly your from email address(mail from: <user@yourEmailAddressDomain.com>) is wrong.

Comment: @webcoder - The exception massage is given at the post. I understand that there is the problem at mail from address. I have been given the address as "Auto Notification TE/AND/DEF". There might be problem with the format or it does not exist.

Comment: It would help to see the exact MAIL FROM command in the [JavaMail debug output](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#debug), as well as the exact code you're using to construct the InternetAddress object.  Most likely the "local address" part of the email address is not being quoted properly.

Answer (score 0):

You say that the mail from address format is like "Auto Notification TE/AND/DEF".

The MAIL FROM command's first argument must be the in the format  where the reverse-path is an email address that errors can be returned to.

"Auto Notification TE/AND/DEF" may be the *name* of an email account, but SMTP doesn't want the name. It wants the address, and "Auto Notification TE/AND/DEF" is not a valid email address.